# How to fetch API in Classes

Tags: javascript, class, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a class which loads external JS files(jQuery libraries) then execute them for fun.

##### Libraries

- [remodal.js](https://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/#)
- [datatables.js](https://datatables.net/)

However, my code throws the error below:

> VM1903:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
> at eval (eval at  (script.js:10:21), :10:4806)
> at eval (eval at  (script.js:10:21), :10:148)
> at eval (eval at  (script.js:10:21), :10:171)
> at script.js:10:21

---

First, I made a regular function without using Class. This worked. No error.

```js
const sources = [
  {
    path: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remodal/1.1.1/remodal.min.js',
    callback: null
  },
  {
    path: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
    callback: () => { document.getElementById('example').DataTable(); }
  },
]
sources.forEach(source => loadFile(source));

function loadFile(source) {
  fetch(source.path)
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(text => eval(text))
    .then(() => source.callback);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a id="remodalOn" href="#modal">Click me!</a>
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close">Close modal</button>
  <h1>Remodal Test</h1>
  <table id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Given name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Harry</td>
        <td>Potter</td>
        <td>17</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lily</td>
        <td>Potter</td>
        <td>40</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Then, I tried to modify it to a class. But `loadFile()` method returned an error.

```js
class ExternalJSfile {
  constructor(path, callback = null) {
    this.path = path;
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  loadFile() {
    fetch(this.path)
      .then(data => data.text())
      .then(text => eval(text))
      .then(() => this.callback);
  }
}

// Load remodal.js
const remodal = new ExternalJSfile(
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remodal/1.1.1/remodal.min.js'
);
remodal.loadFile();

// Load datatables.js and then execute .DataTable()
const dataTables = new ExternalJSfile(
  'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
  () => { document.getElementById('example').DataTable() }
);
dataTables.loadFile();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<a id="remodalOn" href="#modal">Click me!</a>
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close">Close modal</button>
  <h1>Remodal Test</h1>
  <table id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Given name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Harry</td>
        <td>Potter</td>
        <td>17</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lily</td>
        <td>Potter</td>
        <td>40</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Your callback is never called. It should be just `.then(this.callback)`.

Comment: And `DataTable` is only available on the jQuery objects, not `Element` objects. It should be `$('#example').DataTable()`.

Answer (score 0):

The script assumes `this` will be `window`.
When you call `eval` inside a method, `this` refers to the object instance and not `window`.
Since your object has no `jQuery` property, it tries to access `map` on `undefined`.

You need to call `eval` as:

```
eval.call(window, text)
```